# My web page does not render

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am developing a evaluation system. I have set up a dynamic web project in eclipse (with apache tomcat) and have been able to successfully access and view project when accessing it on my local host. However, I just deployed it online (via a war) and when I access the site the web pages do not render. All that is shown is the code. I set the doc type and the content type in an html comment and a meta tag respectively. Why could this be happening? the site is deployed at (REMOVED) as of right now.

Comment: What OS/web server are you running?

Comment: It's coming back with a text/plain content header.  I can see you're using tomcat 6.0.32 but it seems you've mucked up the deployment, though how is not apparent from here.  Try going through an example war and deployment, and see if you're following the right process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) is a great tool to check the HTTP request/responses. Check the *Net* tab. Here are the HTTP response headers which I get when I access the site which you linked in the question:

[image]

Note the content type. It's wrong, it should be `text/html`. If you was using JSP to serve the response, then you probably had like this in top of your JSP

```
<%@page contentType="text/plain" %>
```

you should remove this (it already defaults to `text/html`) or if in vain, replace this by

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" %>
```

If still in vain, contact the support of your hosting.

Comment: The page directive is :<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

Comment: Then it's a server-specific configuration issue at the hosting side. Contact their support, they are the only who can explain/solve this (by the way, alone the `pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"` was been enough, the rest which you've shown are already defaults).

Comment: Hey! Thank you for all your help. Your prompt response and reply was spot on. Apparently my host had the server default set to display in text. I had set the content type with the meta tags and jsp page directives however I needed to call response.setContentType("text/html"); in my servlet. It works thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. But this shouldn't happen or did you had a `response.setContentType("text/plain")` in the servlet?

Comment: No i didn't. I had completely omitted a setContentType call. It is strange because I've deployed the project on a 3 servers now and my host is the only one that needs that line. For the other server the page directives were enough.